# Objective- C - Looping through all properties in a class?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Is there a way to loop through all properties in an object and get their "name" and "value".

I am trying to write a category to serialize objects to a string, based on their property name and values. I'm trying to prevent writing encoding methods for each class, and instead write a generic one.

Is this possible?

Comment: An admirable idea, but down that path lies madness.  You'll be reinventing the wheel (Core Data already provides excellent model based persistence) and the properties system is *not* designed to be the basis for any kind of automated persistency.  The end result will be horribly fragile and will be a complete pain to write in the first place, given the vagaries of C data types.

Comment: Despite my upvote on the "properties please" answer below... THIS is when you need to go learn Core Data. Seriously, it will be worth it. It is not for beginners but IMO once you start doing stuff like hacking the objc runtime it's time to read those strange docs and get your head 'round doing it the right way. :)

Comment: @buildsucceeded I know how to use core data. It's a great solution when it comes to a medium/large sized project that requires relational data. But when it comes to a really small project where all I need to serialize a single object to keep the state of the application, it's an over-kill to use core-data. Plus, I used this solution for other purposes such as Object-To-Dictionary-Serialization and a DI Framework

Comment: True, sometimes the way that seems like madness at first is actually the best. Sounds like you know what you're doing.

Comment: I found a great use case for this, specifically @alex-gray's answer below. I use this for my models, so I can easily serialize them. I just put all the properties that I want sent to my server in my `@interface`, call the method to get a dictionary of them, and then serialize that dictionary calling `[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:content                                    options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
error:&error];
`
That way, as long as the data i want to store is a public property, i can call this method regardless of the type. GREAT question.

Comment: @shadow great, I also used it in other projects. Here is the project that wouldn't get done without this solution: https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper People need to stop questioning the questions and instead answer them hehe. Thanks to Costique

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use this code to enumerate all properties declared in a class, and all attributes of the properties. I guess you're more interested in parsing the type attribute. They are detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html).

```
unsigned int numOfProperties;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &numOfProperties);
for ( unsigned int pi = 0; pi < numOfProperties; pi++ ) {
    // Examine the property attributes
    unsigned int numOfAttributes;
    objc_property_attribute_t *propertyAttributes = property_copyAttributeList(properties[pi], &numOfAttributes);
    for ( unsigned int ai = 0; ai < numOfAttributes; ai++ ) {
        switch (propertyAttributes[ai].name[0]) {
            case 'T': // type
                break;
            case 'R': // readonly
                break;
            case 'C': // copy 
                break;
            case '&': // retain
                break;
            case 'N': // nonatomic 
                break;
            case 'G': // custom getter
                break;
            case 'S': // custom setter
                break;
            case 'D': // dynamic 
                break;
            default: 
                break;
        }
    }
    free(propertyAttributes);
}
free(properties);
```

Comment: Note that no sensible definitions of the various names are exposed for a reason;  it is an implementation detail that may change in the future.

Comment: @bbum Agreed, but the exposed information is useful enough to, say, generate accessor methods for dynamic properties at runtime.

Comment: @Costique what about releasing strings .name, .value in every attribute in attributes array? Who has ownership over them, runtime or developer?

Answer (score 3):

I use the following Category on `NSObject` to say, for example, `NSLog(@"%@", [someObject propertiesPlease]);`, resulting in a log entry like…

```
someObject: {
    color = "NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1";
    crayon = Blueberry;
}
```

<kbd>NSObject+Additions.h</kbd>

```
@interface NSObject (Additions)
- (NSDictionary *)propertiesPlease;
@end
```

<kbd>NSObject+Additions.m</kbd>

```
@implementation NSObject (Additions)
- (NSDictionary *)propertiesPlease {
NSMutableDictionary *props = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
unsigned int outCount, i;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
   objc_property_t property = properties[i];
   NSString *propertyName = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:property_getName(property)];
   id propertyValue = [self valueForKey:(NSString *)propertyName];
   if (propertyValue) [props setObject:propertyValue forKey:propertyName];
}
   free(properties);
   return props;
}
@end
```

Comment: initWithCString is deprecated, [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:property_getName(property) length:strlen(property_getName(property)) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] will work instead.

Comment: Should the return value of `property_getName` be free'd ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `class_copyPropertyList()` will do what you are after - but notice that it only returns declared properties.

Not all properties are declared - `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` are examples of classes where you can set properties that are not declared in the class.

More in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have comment privileges yet, but to add to @Costique's answer, there is an additional attribute Type value "V" which is the name of the IVar to which a property may be bound (via synthesize).  This can be readily discovered with this

@interface Redacted : NSObject

@property (atomic, readonly) int foo;

@end

---

@implementation Redacted

@synthesize foo = fooBar;

@end

```
// for all properties
unsigned propertyCount = 0;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([object class], &propertyCount);
for (int prop = 0; prop < propertyCount; prop++)
{
    // for all property attributes
    unsigned int attributeCount = 0;
    objc_property_attribute_t* attributes = property_copyAttributeList(property, &attributeCount);
    for (unsigned int  attr = 0; attr < attributeCount; attr++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Attribute %d: name: %s, value: %s", attr, attributes[attr].name, attributes[attr].value);
    }
}
```

---

2013-07-08 13:47:16.600 Redacted5162:303] Attribute 0: name: T, value: i

2013-07-08 13:47:16.601 Redacted[5162:303] Attribute 1: name: R, value:

2013-07-08 13:47:16.602 Redacted[5162:303] Attribute 2: name: V, value: fooBar